# CSS in Elmentor

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I know css but i don't understand why my custom CSS dosen't work in elementor.
which selectors to use I don't understand can any one help me with making a sticky and tranparent header which becomes opaque and visible when scrolled down.

I tried selectors like header{} but this just dosen't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a sticky header that changes background color after scrolling, you can set the effects offset for the section where you want it to be sticky. Effects offset refers to the pixel at which the color change will begin. You can adjust these numbers to any values you prefer.

[image]

After that, scroll down to the custom css section and using this code

```css
selector.elementor-sticky--effects{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); /* You change to any color code you want. */ 
}
```

}

*Elementor will add `elementor-sticky--effects` class to the section after it reach the effects offset.

If you are using Elementor, it is not necessary to use any specific class name unless you intend to use the section for JavaScript. You can simply use `selector` within custom CSS.